# Plan already exists - stripe/php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I would like to conclude a monthly plan created by myself with the customer's ID and complete the fixed amount payment.

However, when creating a "Subscription" after creating the original plan, "Plan already exists" is output.

I can not truly understand the above error. For example, if I create and run "Subscription" without creating original plan, the code will work correctly.

The log at that time is below. However, with this, it is impossible to judge what kind of plan contents are adapted to customers. How can you associate your plan with "Subscription"?

## Implement Subscription without creating a plan

```
// echo $customer->id;
// $my_original_plan =  \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
// "id"  => "basic-monthly",
// "interval"  =>  "month",
// "currency"  => "jpy",
// "product" => array("name" => "aaaaaa"),
// "amount"  => 9800
// ));
// echo $my_original_plan;

$subscription =  \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
"customer" => "$customer->id",
"items" => array(
  array(
    "plan" => "basic-monthly",
  ),
)
));

echo $subscription;
```

## The above log

```
Stripe\Subscription JSON: {
    "id": "sub_CXKozer939U80A",
    "object": "subscription",
    "application_fee_percent": null,
    "billing": "charge_automatically",
    "billing_cycle_anchor": 1521674075,
    "cancel_at_period_end": false,
    "canceled_at": null,
    "created": 1521674075,
    "current_period_end": 1524352475,
    "current_period_start": 1521674075,
    "customer": "cus_CXKovj687dz1Po",
    "days_until_due": null,
    "discount": null,
    "ended_at": null,
    "items": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "si_CXKoBTbLbBICEL",
                "object": "subscription_item",
                "created": 1521674075,
                "metadata": [],
                "plan": {
...
```

## Plan already exists

```
// echo $customer->id;

$my_original_plan =  \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
"id"  => "basic-monthly",
"interval"  =>  "month",
"currency"  => "jpy",
"product" => array("name" => "aaaaaa"),
"amount"  => 9800
));

// echo $my_original_plan;


$subscription =  \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
"customer" => "$customer->id",
"items" => array(
array(
"plan" => "basic-monthly",
),
)
));

echo $subscription;
```

## All source code

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
&& strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
if (isset($_POST['request']))
{

//make token from ajax js 
$token_from_js = $_POST['request'];

//stripe from composer
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

//set api key
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_");

//make customer info 
$customer =  \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
"description" => "taylor@example.com",
"source" => "$token_from_js",
));

// echo $customer->id;

$my_original_plan =  \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
"id"  => "basic-monthly",
"interval"  =>  "month",
"currency"  => "jpy",
"product" => array("name" => "aaaaaa"),
"amount"  => 9800
));

// echo $my_original_plan;


$subscription =  \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
"customer" => "$customer->id",
"items" => array(
array(
"plan" => "basic-monthly",
),
)
));

echo $subscription;
};
};

?>
```

Comment: The plan already exists. You don't want to re-create the plan every time you get a new customer, so separate the code for that. (Or just set up plans manually in the Stripe dashboard.)

Comment: Thank you so much My problem was solved thanks to you

Answer (score 1):

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

$product = \Stripe\Product::create([
    'name' => 'My SaaS Platform',
    'type' => 'service',
]);

$plan = \Stripe\Plan::create([
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'interval' => 'month',
    'product' => $product->id,
    'nickname' => 'Pro Plan',
    'amount' => 3000,
]);
```

You should try to use product_id instead of an array.